# Pass URL to CasperJS via CLI

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS to evaluate a webpage. What I would like to do is to let me pass an argument that is a URL, have CasperJS download and evaluate the page, and output to standard out the webpage so I can use it in a BaSH script. Here is my code so far for Casper:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = casper.cli.args;

casper.start(url, function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
        return document;
    });
    this.echo(this.getHTML());
});
casper.run();
```

This is what I'm seeing once I run it:

```
@:~/spider/casperjs$ casperjs viewsource.js google.com
CasperError: No steps defined, aborting                                         
  /usr/local/src/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1510 in run
  ~/spider/casperjs/viewsource.js:10
```

Help please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a variable to a CasperJS script through the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765178/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-casperjs-script-through-the-command-line)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to name your argument :

command :

```
casperjs viewsource.js --url="http://YourUrl.com"
```

script :

```
var mainUrl = casper.cli.get("url");

casper.start(mainUrl)
.then(......)
```

Comment: May be, a small help from my end, if you want to validate the above code with this additional snippet:   `if (!casper.cli.has("url")) { casper.echo("\nUsage:casperjs viewsource.js --url=http://YourUrl.com/").exit(); } `  This would ensure that your below code executes, only if --url is passed in CLI argument list. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
  var url = casper.cli.get(0)
```

Comment: i get @:~/spider/casperjs$ casperjs viewsource.js google.com
<html><head></head><body></body></html>

Comment: So I fixed my script and now it returns the URL twice and does not exit. here is the script:

var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = casper.cli.get(0);

casper.start(url, function () {
 this.echo(url);
});
casper.run(function() {
 this.echo(url).exit;
});

Answer (score 4):

I finally got it. here is the script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = casper.cli.get(0);

casper.start(url, function () {
    this.evaluate(function() {
        return document;
    });
    this.echo(this.getHTML());
});
casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```